# fmt lib check variadic templates arguments with FMT_STRING at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, fmt

I'm creating my own logger implementation. To format the log message I'm using the great FMT lib.
I'd like to check all passed format arguments at compile time using FTM_STRING.
I'm having 2 problems

1. The following results in a compiler error "call to immediate function is not a constant"
2. is it possible to combine default arguments (in my case `std::source_location loc =  std::source_location::current()` with variadic templates.
   I haven't been able to omit the

   std::source_location::current()

in actual function call

```
LoggerTask::log("foo {}",std::source_location::current(),1);
```

.

```
    #include <fmt/format.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <string_view>
    #include <source_location>
    
    class LoggerTask
    {
        public:
        template <typename... Args>
        static void log(
            const std::string_view strMessageToFormat,
            const std::source_location loc =  std::source_location::current(),
            const Args&... args
        );
        private:
        static void log(
          std::string& strFormatedDebugMessage,
          const std::source_location loc
        );
    };
    
    template<typename ...Args>
    void LoggerTask::log(
            const std::string_view strMessageToFormat,
            const std::source_location loc,
            const Args&... args
    )
    {
       std::string strFormatedMessage = fmt::format(FMT_STRING(strMessageToFormat), args...);
       log(strFormatedMessage, loc);
    }
    
    
    void LoggerTask::log(
          std::string& strFormatedDebugMessage,
          const std::source_location loc
          )
    {
      //write some actual log
    }
    
    int main() {
      fmt::print("The answer is {}.", 42);
      LoggerTask::log("foo {}",std::source_location::current(),1);
    }
```

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/8cM119WPz

Could you help me out? Thx guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `FMT_STRING` with a runtime `string_view` which cannot be checked at compile time.

Moreover `FMT_STRING` is a legacy API for older compilers. It is recommended to use `fmt::format_string` instead:

```
template<typename... Args>
void LoggerTask::log(fmt::format_string<Args...> fmt,
                     std::source_location loc,
                     Args&&... args) {
 std::string msg = fmt::format(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 log(msg, loc);
}
```

See also https://fmt.dev/dev/api.html.