# fmt compile time format string check without generating asm code for the check?

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

Is there anyway to ask `fmt` library to do compile time check on the format string against the argument types without generating any asm code (to be compiled out)?

For [example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Cfmt/core.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfmt/compile.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%09fmt::format(FMT_STRING(%22%7B:d%7D%22),+123)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:39.3961179007908,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g111,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:fmt,ver:trunk)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O3%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:60.603882099209194,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4),

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/compile.h>

int main() {
    fmt::format(FMT_STRING("{:d}"), 123);
}
```

Code above does the check (`FMT_STRING` is optional for compiler supporting `constval`) but it also generates some asm code as you can see in the link.

I am looking for a way to trigger the check at compile time without any asm in the final binary.  The reason is that I would like to create my own logger (on top of `fmt`) (similar idea to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74302653/fmt-lib-check-variadic-templates-arguments-with-fmt-string-at-compile-time)) but I would like to defer the actual formatting to another thread later but only have the compile time check done (without any asm code).  Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure, but you could also make a logger that accepts lambdas that do the actual string formatting thus ensuring string formatting only happens when something actually needs to be logged.  e.g. `int value{123}; logger.log([=]{ return fmt::format(FMT_STRING("{:d}"), value);});` (capture by value so logger can even use a background thread for further decoupling from threads running your code). And then logger has a queue like `std::dequeue<std::function<std::string()>>` for things (still) to log

Comment: Are you just [looking for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74317902/2069064)?

Answer (score 3):

Use `static_assert` to check the return value of `formatted_size` with [`FMT_COMPILE`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#format-string-compilation) macro

```
static_assert(fmt::formatted_size(FMT_COMPILE("{:d}"), 123));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5GEhe5fM3)

Comment: there is an edge case where this fails: on empty string: as far as I can tell this is valid `fmt::format(FMT_COMPILE(""))` but will fail your code. In a generic context this can be fixed as `static_assert(fmt::formatted_size(FMT_COMPILE("{:d}"), 123) || true);`. But this is an unusual edge case, don't know how practical it is for the OP to take it into consideration.

Comment: Brilliant!  Odd that using devtoolset-11 (which has g++ 11.2) complained that `fmt::formatted_size()` isn't a `constexpr` function: `fmt/include/fmt/compile.h:572:24: note: ‘size_t fmt::v10::formatted_size(const S&, const Args& ...) [with S = main()::<lambda()>::FMT_COMPILE_STRING; Args = {int}; typename std::enable_if<fmt::v10::detail::is_compiled_string<S>::value, int>::type <anonymous> = 0; size_t = long unsigned int]’ declared here
  572 | FMT_CONSTEXPR20 size_t formatted_size(const S& format_str,
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
`

Answer (score 1):

You can check the format string as follows:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  constexpr auto s = fmt::format_string<int>("{:d}");
}
```

This has no runtime effect as you can see from the generated assembly (https://godbolt.org/z/Eqxa1hf5T):

```
main:
        mov     eax, 0
        ret
```

Normally `format_string` is used as a function argument so that the check is done automatically when the function is called, e.g.

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
void log(fmt::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args) {
  // Format string has already been checked at this point.
  // Do the logging.
}
```

`FMT_STRING` is a legacy mechanism to do the compile-time checks and I wouldn't recommend using it.

I wouldn't recommend using `FMT_COMPILE` for checks either because not all formatters work at compile time and is less efficient because it needs to do unnecessary size computation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Could you give me an example that `FMT_COMPILE` fails to check at compile time?

Comment: Any user defined formatter that doesn't have a constexpr format won't work. Even double may not work on older compilers.

Comment: Let's say I am using newer one like clang 10 or above, is there any concern in using `FMT_STRING` or `FMT_COMPILE`?

Comment: The issues described here are not specific to compiler version.